# Droppable with different size div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery `draggable`, `droppable` and `swappable`, when i drop divs on other i will swap them, and its working great.

Now, we implemented resizing functionality of divs. once we resize divs we are trying to swap both different size divs, but drop event is not calling in this scenario, i tried tolerance to set either "touch" or "pointer" in droppable.

When i use `tolerance:touch` and drag on corner of other divs, all the touching divs are getting affected ( i have 9 divs in my page 3 X 3 divs)

When i use `tolerance:Pointer` and drag big size div on smaller one, by selecting left top of the bigger div, drop event is not calling.

this happens because mouse pointer is not able to reach on top of smaller div. is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Please include your code or better yet include a Fiddle demonstrating your issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NTy6H/1/

Comment: I took a look at your fiddle and could not verify that the swapping was working.  For example if I drag 4 and put it on 3 then 4 disappears.  I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. following is the updated fiddle which explains the situation http://jsfiddle.net/NTy6H/5/ when we drag div "two" on top of div "one", we will get alert message but when we do other way(drag div "one" on top of div "two" by click on left most corner of div "one") we will not get alert as drop event is not called

Comment: I would recommend removing the containment.  That way when when you drag, as long as you have the cursor over the element it should call the drop function.  http://jsfiddle.net/NTy6H/6/

Comment: Hi,  we need containment as we are not allowed to drag any div beyond our main content ("#draggable") as part of our requirement

Comment: You could use the "cursor At" option like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NTy6H/8/ but if you have more then two divs in a row it would not be reliable..  You would have to be able to modify the "cursor At" after checking which direction they are dragging which I tried but was not possible.  Another option would be to not use float left but create three different columns (inline block divs) at roughly (just below 33% or lower depending on padding and margins) of the #draggable container then you could adjust the size of the movables within the column, and still have the cursor reach other moveables

Comment: Hi, I have used drag stop event which will allways called on drag end. so i handled my situation here... thank you.